# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - ./tmp/rspec_guard_result

Tags: ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org, guard

Trying settup rspec-guard-spork for learning app from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Using Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0 on Windows7 ( I know :( )

When starting guard, get:

```
23:02:51 - ERROR - Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its <run_on_modifications>, exception was:
> [#] Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - ./tmp/rspec_guard_result
...
```

All gemfile, guardfile etc are edited according tutorial. Except 1) deleting win32console gem from gemfile because it turned console-out into a crap and raised an error.

Permissions for a file is "F"(ull) for all cattegories:

D:\WebDevelop\sample_app>cacls tmp\rspec_guard_result
D:\WebDevelop\sample_app\tmp\rspec_guard_result

- BUILTIN\Users:(ID)F
- NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated:(ID)F
- BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
- NT AUTHORITY\system:(ID)F

What additional info should I provide here?

Comment: One advice from my experience..you should restart with Linux..I have done the same mistake but then i realized it is not going to complete rather than you will encounter many of other errors which have no relation with Rails and every time you will wonder what has went wrong or do other people don't know the answer..Yes, indeed they don't know the answer to your question cause they never encountered such problem at Linux..so for you smooth learning of RailsTutorial please switch to Linux .thanks :)

Comment: I gues you are right. What Linux distributive would you advice for rails development?

Comment: I think, probably the best one is Ubuntu , but you can go as per your choice and as i am working on Ubuntu and from system end i haven't faced any kind of errors yet, which you usually encounter on Windows.

Comment: One more thing , every time you encounter any issue don't just follow one answer on single post, you should check at-least 4 to 5 post @StackOverflow and after you read them all, decide your path.

Comment: Actually I always try to check as much sources as possible. But I cant find anything about this error. At all. So I writing now this comment from Ubuntu 12.10. Of course it came with another bunch of issues (e.g. Nvidia video drivers setup and much more) but it's wellknown problems and great community helps. I wish I could mark your comment as answer. Thx for ur help!

Comment: I am glad that you switched to Ubuntu and you can see yourself that how much useful is this to use rails on Ubuntu and from here on whichever issue you are going to face, you'll surely get answers to those in StackOverflow..as 80% of RoR developer are using linux and answer to many of the know issues has been resolved already..all the very best :)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a locking problem -- not a permission problem. For me:

C:\Ruby19\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\guard-rspec-4.0.3\lib\guard\rspec\inspector.rb line 51 in def _focused_path. The code tries to delete rspec_guard_result but can't because it's open.  So ... close the file before it gets deleted.

update: as of 11/7/13, the fix is up on https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec (master branch)